# What all stop in an app through task killer in Android

Tags: android

I would like to know what all process will be killed in an app if we use any process killer like task killer?

Will it kill the following:

1. Service
2. Broadcast Receiver
3. Content Observers

All process that keeps running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Any process the app have running well be killed when it is force stopped.